# Mock Unit Test for concurrency C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, mocking

I do have some functions in my controller. Below code is the example:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> NewAccount(Account account)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _Iaccount.NewAccount(account);
            return RedirectToAction("Accounts");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I just want to create a concurrent mock unit test for this function. I tried to create one.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestforNewAccount()
    {
        Mock<IAccount> mock = new Mock<IAccount>();
        var testController = new AccountController(mock.Object);
        Account _account = new Account()
        {
            AccountName = "sample",
            Id = 1,
            AccountNumber = "123",
            Password = "sample"
        };
        mock.Setup(s => s.GetAccountById(1)).Returns(_account);
        IActionResult result = await testController.NewAccount(_account);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(RedirectToActionResult));
    }

    public async Task TestForConcurrentNewAccount()
    {
        await TestforNewAccount();
    }
```

But I think it does not test the concurrency.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to do concurrency on a mock? What behavior is it that you are trying to test?

Comment: HI Nkosi, I'm trying to test the concurrency. I'm trying to create a unit test that would check 2 user's can insert record at the same time.

Comment: I get that. My question is WHY. there is nothing to test here, at least based on what is shown in the example. The method under test is calling a mock. Note though that your method under test looks incomplete. It is tagged as async Task but there is not acync functionality there.

Comment: yeah, its just my example. i dont have any idea yet with creating unit test. If you can show me the proper unit test, I would gladly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Generally, if you want to test concurrency safety, you should do some [fuzz testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing). Of course, you can only detect failures; you could never *prove* your system is threadsafe unless you run it on a virtual CPU.

Comment: Coyote is .NET library and tool designed to help ensure that your code is free of concurrency bugs. 

https://microsoft.github.io/coyote/